# Ubuntu connecting nfs4 client with minor version 0

Tags: linux, ubuntu, nfs

I am trying to connect NFS client in Ubuntu server 18 and force it to use minor version 0 so the NFS will be of 4.0.
I am trying to use:
sudo mount -t nfs4 -o minorversion=0 server_ip:shared local_shared/

but no luck, without the parameters it connects well but in version 4.2

Thanks,
Yoav

Comment: `without the parameters it connects well but in version 4.2` – And what issue does this version bring? Please make sure there is no [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/355310) here.

Comment: For sure my real problem is not connecting in NFS4.0 but something else, but our system uses a lot of IO and we encounter some problems with NFS4.2 and know in 4.0 it works good.
So for fast solution I need to start with using 4.0.
and can't make the minorvesrion option to work, any ideas?